# What do I need to know when building a Video Editing Workstation?

Tags: video, video-editing, computer-building

I want a new workstation with some super duper hardware. I'm planning for this to be a purpose-built video editing station, and I don't know quite where to start!

What should I look for when building in this system?

Comment: -1 Wrong question to ask. I suggest you ask for actual advice.

Comment: @digitxp - This isn't a shopping website, so this question seems fine to me as he's not asking for shopping recommendations, he's asking for where to look for shopping recommendations!

Comment: Where to look for shopping recommendations isn't what we're about, either.  But what we can do is answer the question in a way that fits the site.  In this case: "what information does he need to do his own shopping?"

Answer (score 1):

Video editing is one of those rare cases where a multi-core machine really makes sense.  You want a machine with 4 or even one of the new six-core i7s, and lots of RAM.  If you've got money to spend and are doing some *really* serious video editing I might even go dual-Xeon (6 cores * 2 cpus * 2 for hyperthreading = 24 logical processors).

A fast hard drive doesn't hurt either, though I think I might prefer 2 WD Raptors in RAID-0 over an SSD in this case.

Finally, some editing software supports off-loading some of the processing to video cards.  Typically, when software supports this it will only support it for cards from *either* nVidia or ATi, but not both.  You should check your software and make sure to choose a supported video card to be able to take advantage of this feature.